# CSS3 height:75% doesn't want to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

Here's what I'm trying to do http://www.zabkaspace.me/will/

As you can see, there's a div, with thumbnails on it, and it's scrollable. But the problem is that this div got a size fixed with a specific size (380px). I've try a lot of different settings, and I can't use a size using % and not px ... I don't understand why ^^

Here's my code :

HTML part :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='hidden-scrollbar'>
    <div class='inner'>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6"> <img src="img/tt.jpg" width="100%">   </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">  <img src="img/tt.jpg" width="100%"> </div>
      </div>

        <!-- More content -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS part :

```
.hidden-scrollbar {
  height: 380px;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

.hidden-scrollbar .inner {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0px -300px 15px 0px;
  padding-right:300px; 
}
```

The container class is from Bootstrap 3.

The problem is that when I replace

```
height: 380px;
```

by (in .hidden-scrollbar)

```
height: 75%;
```

It screws evrything up ! Anyone got an idea of why setting the size in % doesn't work ? :)

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to get, but I think, that you need the parent to have an height of 100%, and so on, because if the .hidden-scrollbar has an height in %, the browser, doesn't know what percentage it is...

Comment: Here's how it looks like when i use height:75% : http://www.zabkaspace.me/will/index2.html

Comment: Well Tio, I've specified for .container, .body and .html a height:100% ...

Comment: This what I get after adding 100% height to html tag http://imgur.com/etNC06m, is this what you are trying to achieve? For this, I add to give 100% to html, body, .container, @Zabka

Comment: On your pic, the height of the hidden-scrollbar class is set on what ?

Comment: -__- Tio thanks, I just saw that in my css, I setted height:100% evrywhere, but in my .html I gotted min-height only ... Thanks, it's now working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't know what 75% of height is without the parents having their height defined, in this case, you need to give an height to their parents.

So your CSS, needs to have the following:

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    height:100%;
}

.hidden-scrollbar {
    height:75%;
}
```

Which gives me the following:
[image]